# Do monomials' degrees always depend on the whole-number exponent of the variable or whether it's a constant (having a degree of zero)?

Tags: polynomials

Is it true that the monomial $4x^4$ has a degree of $4$ because of the exponent?  Also, I think $-2x$ has a degree of $1$ because it has an exponent of $1$ when it's also written like this: $-2x^1$.  It's the same thing.  Also, constants, like $94$, have a degree of zero because it's equal to $94x^0$, which simplifies to $94\cdot1$ and then equals $94$.  Also, monomials can be listed into a polynomial according to their degrees like this:$$10x^4-x^3+4x^2+3x-1$$Does this really happen depending on the whole-number exponent of the variable or if it's a constant?

Comment: $94=94x^0$. So in short, I think you've got it.

Comment: Got it right now! ;)

Comment: Why not google "monomial degree" to [get this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial#Degree) as the top hit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The degree of a monomial is the sum of all the exponents of the variables in the monomial.

Examples:

The degree of $97$ is $0$ because $97=97x^0$.

The degree of $4x^2$ is $2$ because the exponent $2$ is the only exponent involved.

The degree of $xyzw$ is $4$ because each of the four variables has degree $1$, so $1+1+1+1=4$.

The degree of $x^2y^3z^5w^7$ is $17$ because the sum of the exponent's variables gives us $2+3+5+7=17$.